# reopen a directory using openat

Tags: c, linux

As it seems, it is possible to use `openat()` to *re*open an already opened directory. For instance on my Linux system I can do the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int fd1 = open(".", O_PATH);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    int fd2 = openat(fd1, ".", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("openat");
        close(fd1);
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd1);

    // do fancy things with fd2, now opened
    // with access mode read-only

    return 0;
}
```

I could not find this documented anywhere and it feels a bit like an edge case. Also I didn't find other code doing this. Is this well-defined behavior?

EDIT: changed the title: file -> directory

Comment: You can open a file for reading more than once anyway.

Comment: first in both cases you are simply getting a dirfd back and `dirfd` in any _at functions is used to resolve relative path., so the behavior is still well defined

Comment: You can't do this with a file, only with a directory, since `.` is the name of the directory relative to itself.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, I'll update the title accordingly to make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the same as calling `open` twice on the same file, which you are allowed to do:

```
int fd1 = open("filename", flags1);
int fd2 = open("filename", flags2);
```

where `filename` refers to an existing file (of any type) and `flags1` and `flags2` are any set of `O_` flags that can be validly applied to that type of file and won't destroy its contents.  (In particular, we assume that they do not include `O_CREAT`, `O_TRUNC`, or `O_EXCL`.)

`fd1` and `fd2` will refer to separate "[open file descriptions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195097/21167)", so for instance `lseek` on one will not affect the other, `flock` on one will block `flock` on the other, etc.

Answer (score 3):

With [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html), the first argument, `fd`, should be the file descriptor for a directory — such as the one you obtained from opening `"."` — or the special value `AT_FDCWD` (which means open relative paths relative the current directory).  Note that the `O_PATH` option you use is a Linux-only extension to [`openat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/openat.2.html).

So, because you're using a valid file descriptor for a directory, the call to `openat()` should succeed.  You now have two file descriptors both pointing (independently — with separate open file descriptions) to the current directory.  In general, it is possible to open the same file multiple times in a single process (or in multiple processes — ensuring access by a single process is actually very hard on Unix-like (POSIX) systems).

There isn't a lot else you can do with those descriptors other than use them in `*at()` system calls.  Either of the file descriptors would have been sufficient; opening both was overkill.