# Why are there open syscalls with empty file names?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, ebpf

When I use [opensnoop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/opensnoop.py) to watch file access I see a lot of open syscalls with empty file name. For example, `strace cat foobar` consistently produces one syscall with empty filename,

```
$ sudo python3 opensnoop.py 
PID    COMM               FD ERR PATH
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/present
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now
3819   upowerd            -1   2 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_max_design
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_min_design
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/status
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/power_now
3819   upowerd            -1   2 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full
3819   upowerd            -1   2 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design
3819   upowerd            -1   2 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/current_now
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_now
3819   upowerd            10   0 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
3819   upowerd            -1   2 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/temp
137272 strace              3   0 /etc/ld.so.cache
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind-ptrace.so.0
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind-x86_64.so.8
137272 strace              3   0 
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
137272 strace              3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8
137272 strace              3   0 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
137272 strace              3   0 /usr/share/locale/locale.alias
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137272 strace             -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                 3   0 /etc/ld.so.cache
137275 cat                 3   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
137275 cat                 3   0 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
137275 cat                -1   2 foobar
137275 cat                 3   0 /usr/share/locale/locale.alias
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
137275 cat                -1   2 /usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
```

Is there a reason for such behaviour? If I want to trace file accesses do I have to treat empty file names differently? Would I miss anything by filtering them out?

I actually tried opening empty filename, but that gives an error:

```c
// example.c
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/54793898/1374078
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int fd1 = open(".", O_PATH);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int fd2 = openat(fd1, "", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("openat");
        close(fd1);
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd1);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -ox example.c && ./x
openat: No such file or directory
```

So how do empty file names get to syscalls?

**UPDATE**
Here is output of `strace`

```
$ strace strace cat foobar 2>&1 | grep open
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind-ptrace.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind-x86_64.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/etc/ld.so.cac"..., 55openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 55
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/lib/x86_64-li"..., 70openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 70
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/lib/local"..., 69openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 69
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"foobar\", O_RDO"..., 35openat(AT_FDCWD, "foobar", O_RDONLY) = 35
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 69openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 69
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 77openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 77
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 72openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 72
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 74openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 74
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 69openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 69
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 86openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 86
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 81openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 81
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 83openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 83
write(2, "openat(AT_FDCWD, \"/usr/share/loc"..., 78openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 78
```

Comment: Paths and file names that contain non printable characters are still valid and `opensnoop.py` will report them, but you won't be able to see them on the terminal. For example, if you try to do `open("\x01\x02\x03", O_RDONLY)` in your C program.

Comment: What is the result of "strace strace cat foobar 2>&1 | grep open" ?

Comment: Added command output @RachidK.

Comment: It seems that the "empty" name concerns the C library (libc.so.6). Would it be a bug from the opensnoop tool?